# Newtonsoft JSON for .net is ignoring jsonproperty tags

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

For some really irritating reason, the JsonProperty tags are not working with Newtonsoft's Json for .net tool. In my class I have these:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "class")]
    public string EventClass { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
    public string Start { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "end")]
    public string End { get; set; }
```

But I am receiving this

```
{"success":true,
 "result": [{
    "ID":"0",
    "Title":"Eid ul-Fitr",
    "Url":"<blah>",
    "EventClass":"event-info",
    "Start":"1406520000000",
    "End":"1406606400000"},
  etc.
```

As you can see it is ignoring me setting the property name. I have tried using `[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name="id")]` as well and that has not worked.

Here is what is really driving me up the wall. It worked yesterday. I rolled it back to where it was last night when I committed and it still won't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might want to share your code.

Comment: Why when I serialize does it ignore PropertyNames I assigned it.

Comment: How are you serializing the class?  Please show your code.

Comment: I'm just calling Json(MyClass) and returning it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you sure you're actually serializing using Json.Net?  `Json(MyClass)` is an ASP.NET MVC method. MVC uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class, which does not support `[JsonProperty]` attributes.  To use the attributes, you would need to serialize using the Json.Net method `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyClass)`.  If you want to return that JSON from within an MVC controller then you would need call `Content(jsonString, "application/json")` instead of `Json()`.