# How to use conditional serialization in Asp.Net MVC 5.x?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

In my controller I am returning an object of a class with ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}() methods in it but it looks like these methods are not called when MVC action methods are invoked. I even tried returning 'false' as you see commented out in the code below with no luck.

```
public Department Department { get; set; }

public bool ShouldSerializeDepartment()
{
    return Department != null;
    // return false;
}
```

That means, Asp.Net MVC does not call JsonConvert.SerializeObject behind the scenes otherwise conditional serialization would  be effective (Am I right?).

Does anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: Correct, ASP.NET MVC 5 does not use Json.Net; it uses `JavaScriptSerializer`.  Therefore it will not honor Json.Net attributes or `ShouldSerialize` methods.  See [Newtonsoft JSON for .net is ignoring jsonproperty tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24897579/10263).  See also [Setting the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14591750/10263).

Comment: thanks @BrianRogers, that sheds lights on this dilemma of mine :)
if you put it as an answer I will mark it as the right one.