# JSON.NET NullValueHandling in JsonPropertyAttribute not working as expected

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class like so:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Condition
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expressions", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IEnumerable<Expression> Expressions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "logical_operation")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public LogicOp? LogicalOperation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AssessmentExpressionTypeConverter))]
    public ExpressionType Type { get; set; }
}
```

However, when the `Expressions` property is null, and I serialize the object like so:

```
 var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(condition, Formatting.Indented);
```

... the text of the Json string has the line:

```
"expressions": null
```

My understanding is that this should not happen.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this? Running into same problem, the attribute on the property has no effect.

Comment: In my case, the serialization of that object was overriden with a custom `CustomCreationConverter`, but you could also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424151/json-net-serializer-ignoring-jsonproperty?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

The default text serializer used by .net API is System.Text.Json:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

So if you want to ignore if null you can use:

**[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]**

Example:

```
public class Forecast
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never)]
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This question is 7 years old; at the time it was asked, JSON.NET was the de facto JSON serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)] instead

Answer (score 1):

add this service on `Startup.cs` :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }` as third parameter in JsonConvert.SerializeObject method.

Comment: Hmmm... there are quite a few properties that I *do* want to render as `null` though, and I think that will apply a blanket policy for the entire serialization.