# JsonProperty on C# Records in Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, c#-9.0

With the new C# record types in C# 9 i'd like to know wheter it is possible (for serialization) to set the `JsonPropertyAttribute` from Newtonsoft.Json on the constructor parameter.
It doesn't seem to work out of the box.

MWE:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Something("something")));

record Something([JsonProperty("hello")] string world) {}
```

Output:

```
{"world":"something"}
```

Expected output:

```
{"hello":"something"}
```

is there an easy way to make it work like this? or do we have to revert back to the property style with a real constructor?

```
internal record Something
{
    public Something(string world) { World = world; }

    [JsonProperty("hello")] public string World { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#properties):

> Attributes can be applied to the synthesized auto-property and its backing field by using `property:` or `field:` targets for attributes syntactically applied to the corresponding record parameter.

So you want

```
record Something([property:JsonProperty("hello")] string world) {}
```

Without the `property:` qualifier, the attribute ends up on the parameter of the generated constructor (which is useful in other scenarios, like nullability).

Comment: In my latest VS19 preview, without `property:` compilation breaks with ie `Attribute 'JsonIgnore' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations.`

Comment: @kofifus: sure, but that has nothing to do with the syntax as such, but that `JsonIgnore` has an `AttributeUsage` attribute that prohibits use on parameters. Whether or not that's allowed is specific per attribute.