# Upgrading from .net5 to .net7 Json Serialization stopped working

Tags: c#, json, .net-7.0, system.text.json

We had an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API backend alongside a ReactJS UI app. In startup we instantiated the json framework the following way:

```
services.AddControllers()
 .AddNewtonsoftJson()
 .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

It was working well alongside "JsonPropertyName" attributes, i.e. the following property was correctly received in javascript as `interfaceId`:

```
[JsonPropertyName("interfaceId")]
public long INTERFACE_ID { get; set; }
```

Eventually, some guy decided it would be a good idea to upgrade the projects to .NET 7, which caused json serialization to stop working. Above example was received in Javascript as `interfacE_ID` (the lower and uppercase characters are exactly that way). The same way, json objects sent from Javascript to Web API stopped being auto serialized into C# objects (getting a http 400 response), so I have to switch my controller declaration from

```
public IActionResult Insert([FromBody] Rol entity) => this.Ok(this.service.Insert(entity));
```

to

```
public IActionResult Insert([FromBody] JToken entity) => this.Ok(this.service.Insert(entity.ToObject<Rol>()));
```

I have seen in this post [JSON.Net serializer ignoring JsonProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424151/json-net-serializer-ignoring-jsonproperty) that, probably, could be a conflict on json.net (or newtonsoft.json) versions, so I cleaned everything and updated all nuget packages, removing `System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json` packages, keeping only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.

I also tried to apply explicit json naming converters like those proposed in this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/, but at the moment I achieved nothing.
As I'm not an expert in .net7, I would like to know where could be the problem located or if I'm missing a configuration step required for the new framework.

Thanks

Edit: Thank you very much to everyone

Attribute modification proposed by @Serge worked, so Newtonsoft.Json was the serializer which handled the requests.
So, I removed `.AddNewtonsoftJson()` from my startup.cs and the output serialization (web api to Javascript) began working well again.

I'm still facing input serialization issues (HTTP 400), I guess related to .net7 nullable policies, so I'm looking for a way to get the proper validation error which triggers the HTTP 400 response

Comment: You have tagged this Json.NET but `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` and `JsonSerializerOptions` are both from System.Text.Json.  So that's the serializer you were using in .NET 5.  And this serializer does not support `JToken` which is from Json.NET.  So in .NET 7 you must actually be mixing them somehow.  Try to disentangle which you are using, and use only one consistently.  If things worked in .NET 5, and you were using System.Text.Json in .NET 5, try removing all `using Newtonsoft` from your .NET 7 code and see if reverting back to System.Text.Json fixes things.

Comment: You are getting error 400 which is bad request.  Your connection is completing and authentication is passing which means the token is good.  Only way of solving is to debug the server code and find out why serve does not like the request.  Error 400 can mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix the name attribute from System.Text.Json to Newtonsoft.Json

```
[JsonProperty("interfaceId")]
public long INTERFACE_ID { get; set; }
```

and since you are using Net7 in some cases to avoid a validation error (400) would be usefull

```
[JsonProperty("interfaceId")]
public long? INTERFACE_ID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer was a mix between al of your responses. I, finally, decided to remove Newtonsoft.Json, keeping System.Text.Json and adapt my model classes to avoid .net7 null properties validation